# Materialize Css - Materialzie select multiple scrolling when selecting option

Tags: angularjs, materialize, apache-cordova

Hi I am  using materialize css for my apache cordova application . I am using materialze multiple select  in  a form  .It is working fine in browser platform  .
But when i running it in apache cordova when i am  selecting multiple options it is scrolling to selected option .

Can any one tell me the answer. Here is the code:

```
<select id="service_type" materialize-Select required ng-if="serviceTypes" multiple>
  <option value="" disabled selected>
    Choose Service Type
  </option>
  <option ng-repeat="serviceType in serviceTypes" ng-value="serviceType.service_id" ng-click="getServiceTypes();">
    {{serviceType.service_type}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you share your code here

Comment: <select id="service_type"  materialize-Select required
                                    ng-if="serviceTypes" multiple >
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Service Type</option>
        
        <option  ng-repeat="serviceType in serviceTypes" ng-value="serviceType.service_id" ng-click="getServiceTypes();">{{serviceType.service_type}}</option>
                               
                            </select>

Answer (score 0):

That is the wanted behavior that materialize's team decided to implement;
as referenced here:
https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3448
you can remove line 3280 of dist/materialize.js file to avoid it;

that's a kind of hack I know...